# Can I enable Unicode UTF-8 WorldWide Support in WIndows 11, but set another encoding for a specific app?

Tags: windows, unicode, windows-11, utf-8

generally, I like to enable UTF-8 worldwide support in Windows 11, because most of apps  I use support UTF-8 and I am using Linux OS with UTF-8 at the same time.

But the problem I had so far is one of apps that I have to use is only working in non-UTF-8  environment. If I enable UTF-8 support in Windows 11, the app won't display words correctly (unreadable chars shown in GUI).

**Note:** I have set the app's required language in `Current system locale` in Region Settings at the same GUI window when enabling UTF-8 worldwide. But that doesn't help at all.

Thus, I am wondering if I can enable UTF-8 worldwide and use another non-UTF8 encoding for a special app at the same time in Windows 11.

Thanks a lot.

**Edited 1:**

I am trying the app https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator

I am not sure if that can fix the encoding issue or not, currecntly, my app can not be started because the requried files can not be read after using Locale-Emulator. I am trying to figure out how to make my app run with it.

**Edited 2:**

I think `Locale-Emulator` won't fix my problem.

And most online articles are talking about setting the option `Currenet language for non-Unicode Programs` will fix their problems. BUT as what I mentioned in the original question above, I have set this to the correct language that my app uses. But it doesn't help. It will still show unreadable (unrecognized) characters.

After googling for very long time, I have lost faith in solving this problem.

Maybe, I just disable UTF-8 in windows then. This is very ugly. *Why does Windows use non-UTF8 in the beginning anyway? This is a wrong decision from the beginning that causes all the troubles. (Sorry about the conmplain. I am getting crazy with this).*

The app which requires non-Unicode is for my job. So I have to use it.

**Edited3:**

How to enable UTF-8:

- `Control Panel` > `Clock and Region` > `Region` > `Administrative` tab > `Change system locale` button > enable `Beta:Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`.
- The same GUI window can also be launched from `Settings` > `Time & Language` > `Language & region` > `Administrative language settings` > `Administrative` tab > `Change system locale` button > enable `Beta:Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`.

Comment: I remember the AppCompat feature in XP allowed forcing a different "system locale" for specific apps, but I don't know if it has an equivalent anymore...

Comment: @user1686 According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/january-25-2022-kb5008353-os-build-22000-469-preview-920e6297-567b-4b95-afe9-35d17de02c3a (search for `appcompat`) it still has the same name in Windows 11

Comment: AppCompat as a whole, yes, but the custom system locale module was installable separately (from some kind of resource kit, I think?). I remember using it to force a Russian locale for some old non-unicode apps.

Comment: Does the app work if you right-click its `.exe`, select Properties, Compatibility tab, check "Run this program in compatibility mode for" and select a very old Windows version? How do you set UTF-8 for the entire Windows?

Comment: @harrymc, it will only work when I disable UTF-8 in windows 11, otherwise it will show unreadable words. This is an encoding issue, not a compatibility issue. I think there is only one way to set UTF-8 in windows. I will not describe the detail here. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @harrymc: To clarify: in case you think I used some weird way to setup UTF-8, I use the proper GUI way to setup UTF-8 in Windows. And there should be only one GUI place to set it up. Thanks.